# File not found error in attempt to play audio (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm new to this, so in an attempt to keep things simple, I'm trying to add sound into my main.m

As far as I know, the following code should work, but when I run it, I get a "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)" (File not found)"

I've tried it with various audio files and formats - added to the project in Xcode but can't figure out why it isn't finding my G1.wav

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/G1.wav"]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog([error description]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
```

EDIT removed NSBundle and mainBundle references - my misunderstanding

Comment: When you look at your app bundle, does the file actually end up at Whatever.app/Contents/Resources/G1.wav? If it's not, that's why you're getting a "File not found" error, and the solution is to figure out what you're doing wrong in Xcode to get the file into the wrong place. If it is, then there's a different problem. It'll be a lot easier to diagnose if we know which it is.

Comment: So I'm now pretty sure I got confused and added the NSBundle lines when it wasn't working. I've now replaced the line back to 'NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"G1.wav"]];' and it doesn't work. I don't have an app bundle. All I've done is drag the G1.wav file into my Supporting File and assumed that the above line would be right...but sadly file not found

Comment: Fixed it by moving to cocoa-based project away from command line. It meant I could actually refer to the bundle.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off with this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"G1" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
...
```

Using `pathForResource:ofType:` you don't have to worry about where in the hierarchy of your bundle the file is. The API call figures it out. And in your code, whatever `resourcePath` is returning is clearly not the right path.

You might add some `NSLog()` calls here and there to see what is really happening, as well.

Comment: Unless you need to deal with OS X 10.5 or iOS 3, there's no good reason to call pathForResource:ofType: and then fileURLWithPath: on the result, when you can just call URLforResource:withExtension: directly. More importantly, this doesn't actually solve the user's problem, since you're specifying the exact same path as his original code did, just in a different way.

Comment: @abamert: `URLForResource:withExtension:` wasn't what first came to mind when I answered. That is clearly a good thing to use here. To your second point, I would disagree. The OP is constructing a path by concatenating the result of `resourcePath` and the file name. `resourcePath` is simply the path to the directory containing resources, not a resource-specific path, which is what he needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i fixed it by moving to a cocoa-based app so i could refer to the bundle.I think Command line needed a more exact pointing to the file.